# Two non-isomorphic separable Banach spaces that are universally isometric

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm looking for two non-isomorphic Banach spaces which are universally isometric.

What I mean by universally isometric is the following:

A separable Banach space $X$ is universally isometric if given any other separable Banach space $Y$, there exists an isometry $j: Y \longrightarrow X$.

I know that $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ is universally isometric so in fact, I'm looking for another universally isometric space that is not isomorphic to $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$. I'm also looking for good references for these facts. I mean, some books or papers where it is proven that the new space is universally isometric and that is not isomorphic to $\mathcal{C}([0,1])$ .

Comment: $C[0,1]\oplus_1\ell_2$ should work (it is not isomorphic to $C[0,1]$ since $C[0,1]$ does not contain an infinite dimensional, complemented, reflexive subspace).

Comment: How can I prove that $\mathcal{C}[0,1]$ does indeed not contain an infinite dimensional, complemented, reflexive subspace?

Comment: One shows $C[0,1]$ has the "Dunford-Pettis property", and, as a consequence, the square of a weakly compact operator from the space to itself is compact. The result then follows. Details can be found, e.g., in Kalton and Albiac's *Topics in Banach Space Theory*.